# how to onclick change image between 3 images

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

Hi I am new to javascript and I want to change the image when I click the image. I can do this with 2 images, how do I do this with 3 images?

```js
function change() {
  var image = document.getElementById('changeimg');
  console.log(image)
  switch (image) {
    case "image2":
      document.getElementById('changeimg').src = "css3.png";
      break;
    default:
    case "image3":
      document.getElementById('changeimg').src = "javascript.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Change Image</h1>
<br>
<div class="container" align="center">
  <img src="html5.png" style="height: 500px; width: 500px" id="changeimg" onclick="change()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your real image name in the `imgArr`

```js
var img = 0;
var imgArr = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"]

function change() {
  
  var image = document.getElementById('changeimg');
  console.log("Current image => ", imgArr[img])
  document.getElementById('changeimg').src = imgArr[img];
  if (img == 2) img = 0;
  else 
    img++;

}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Change Image</h1>
<br>
<div class="container" align="center">
  <img src="html5.png" style="height: 500px; width: 500px" id="changeimg" onclick="change()">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have added a button "Next" to go on the next img, and it works with the code you wrote above. I want to add a button "Previous" what function code will work that will go back one img? thanks for the help btw!